# SQL syntax change with H2 version update

Tags: spring-boot, testing, h2

I am having the following script for H2 DB used in SpringBoot application tests:

```
create TABLE PARAMETER (
  ID long auto_increment,
  TYPE VARCHAR(100) not null,
  VALUE VARCHAR(100) not null,
  SORT_ORDER int not null
);

CREATE SEQUENCE PARAMETER_ID_SEQ MINVALUE 1 START WITH 1;
```

This script executes with previous H2 version `<h2.version>1.4.196</h2.version>`, but when updating to `<h2.version>2.1.210</h2.version>` the following error ocures and I cannot understand what the problem. Is there a new syntax with the upper version?

ERROR:

```
Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Syntax error in SQL statement "create TABLE PARAMETER (\000a  ID long [*]auto_increment,\000a  TYPE VARCHAR(100) not null,\000a  VALUE VARCHAR(100) not null,\000a  SORT_ORDER int not null\000a);\000a\000aCREATE SEQUENCE PARAMETER_ID_SEQ MINVALUE 1 START WITH 1;"; expected "RAW, ARRAY, INVISIBLE, VISIBLE, NOT, NULL, AS, DEFAULT, GENERATED, ON, NOT, NULL, DEFAULT, NULL_TO_DEFAULT, SEQUENCE, SELECTIVITY, COMMENT, CONSTRAINT, COMMENT, PRIMARY, UNIQUE, NOT, NULL, CHECK, REFERENCES, ,, )"; SQL statement:
create TABLE PARAMETER (
  ID long auto_increment,
  TYPE VARCHAR(100) not null,
  VALUE VARCHAR(100) not null,
  SORT_ORDER int not null
);

CREATE SEQUENCE PARAMETER_ID_SEQ MINVALUE 1 START WITH 1; [42001-210] [Failed SQL: (42001) create TABLE PARAMETER (
  ID long auto_increment,
  TYPE VARCHAR(100) not null,
  VALUE VARCHAR(100) not null,
  SORT_ORDER int not null
);

CREATE SEQUENCE PARAMETER_ID_SEQ MINVALUE 1 START WITH 1;]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There is no such data type as `long` in SQL, where did you find it? You need to use `BIGINT`. H2 accepts `long` too, but it depends on compatibility mode, for example, it isn't allowed in PostgreSQL compatibility mode.
2. `AUTO_INCREMENT` should also be used only in MySQL and MariaDB compatibility modes, H2 also accepts it in REGULAR and LEGACY modes, but normally you need to use `GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY`.
3. `VALUE` is a keyword in H2 and it also a reserved word in the SQL Standard (even in archaic SQL-92). You cannot use it as an identifier without quotes, you need to write it as `"VALUE"` or `"value"` depending on case you want (quoted identifiers are case-sensitive by default). Actually there is a compatibility setting, you can add `;NON_KEYWORDS=VALUE` to JDBC URL of H2, but it would be better to quote it in your scripts and application.

Comment: This is iherited code and it worked, which amazed me until I updated the h2 version. 'long' was strange to me as well the 'VALUE' column. However changes at the same time fixed the script, thanks a lot